# How can I use an image as pattern to paste uniformaly on a svg path to be drawn on canvas via fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am working on an app where I have to design shoes, on their specific parts which are svg paths drawn on canvas, like heels, front face. I have to give options of materials to be selected to mount over these parts/paths.

A common situations you can find on the given link.
[here](https://www.shoesofprey.com/3d/designer?p=RP100-T3-B1)

My code: The issue is I am not getting product like finishing of pattern on the drawn `paths()`the granular pattern of real material as in above given example url.

```
 var img_obj = new Image();
 img_obj.src = 'texture2.jpg';



 for (var i = 0; i < shape.paths.length; i++) {
        shape.paths[i].setPatternFill({
                    source: img_obj,
                    repeat: 'repeat'
                });
                alert(shape.paths[i]);
            }

  canvas.add(shape);
  canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to apply a texture. Take a look at compositing -- perhaps `overlay`. Hard to say more without your seeing your design.

Comment: Thanks Mark I hope, your pointer will help me, exactly I am drawing svg on canvas and want to apply some material texture on different paths, like suppose for a shoe on upper leather I want to give a red leather texture. plz leave few more pointers which can help me, I apologize for a late  acknowledgement to your help.